# ParseFacebookUtils i386 missing architecture

Tags: ios, parse-platform, rubymotion

I am trying to use Parse iOS SDK and including the ParseFacebookUtils but anytime I include it I get an error about

```
ld: framework not found Parse for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I can't seem to figure out what is going on, if I remove the requirement for `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` everything compiles fine.

Any idea what is up?

Comment: Also having that problem.. haven't gone deep on it though. There are some possible solutions posted in the RubyMotion google group, but none of them worked for me.